# How can i select values from the same table, comparing values on each line?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get the `ID` values where the `AL` and `DATE` are the same, but the ID are diferent, from the same table.
I've tried like this:

```
SELECT a.AL,a.ID,a.date 
FROM 
 tabel a,
 tabel b
where a.id <>  b.id
AND a.al = b.al                      
AND  a.date LIKE '%20201016%'
GROUP BY  a.id,a.al ,a.date
```

Table

```
AL  ID  date
10  400 20201016
20  400 20201016
30  100 20201016
20  100 20201016
10  100 20201016
10  300 20201016
```

But its returning repetitive values.
I need that the result be like:

```
AL  ID  date
10  400 20201016
10  100 20201016
10  300 20201016
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than performing a self-join, you can use analytic functions (and only query the table once):

```sql
SELECT AL,
       ID,
       "DATE"
FROM   (
  SELECT AL,
         ID,
         "DATE",
         COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY al )
           - COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY al, id ) AS cnt,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY al ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name
  WHERE  "DATE" >= DATE '2020-10-16'
  AND    "DATE" <  DATE '2020-10-16' + INTERVAL '1' DAY
)
WHERE  cnt > 0
AND    rn  = 1;
```

*(Note: rather than comparing dates as strings you can use `TRUNC` to remove the time part or compare on a range of dates from midnight of the day up until midnight of the next day; a date range is better as it would then use an index on the column whereas using `TRUNC` would require a specific function-based index.)*

So, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( AL, ID, "DATE" ) AS
SELECT 10, 400, DATE '2020-10-16' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20, 400, DATE '2020-10-16' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 30, 100, DATE '2020-10-16' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 20, 100, DATE '2020-10-16' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 100, DATE '2020-10-16' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 300, DATE '2020-10-16' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> AL |  ID | DATE     
> -: | --: | :--------
> 10 | 100 | 16-OCT-20
> 10 | 300 | 16-OCT-20
> 10 | 400 | 16-OCT-20
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=37cb1f54cafcd70c2e07951922e0aa40)*

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `exists` and a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*
from mytable t1
where exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where t1.al = t.al and t1.date = t.date and t1.id <> t.id
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `<>` when comparing the ids, use `<`:

```
SELECT a.AL,a.ID,a.date 
FROM 
 tabel a,
 tabel b
where a.id < b.id
AND a.al = b.al                      
AND  a.date LIKE '%20201016%'
GROUP BY  a.id, a.al ,a.date
```

You are getting duplicates because you check every row against every other row in both directions.  Checking only "less than" means these duplicates will not appear.